# Auto snapping behaviour

Tags: snapping

When using LoopCut, some vertices snap on each other. I don't have snapping enabled.
how can I turn off this behaviour :D
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hM5HK3Pi8Qo

Comment: does this also snap if you turn off your speed sculpt add-on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turn off the vertex automerge option shown below.
[image]

Comment: Ty, so simple haha but never noticed that icon b 4.

Comment: You're not alone! :^)